# I am trying to post an add using my app but no response and server error . I am using Volley Library

Tags: android

I am trying to post an add using android app but unable to do that no response from server. server error am using volley library
my app is connected with internet and i have some my differnt classes

public class User_AddPost extends AppCompatActivity
{

```
Spinner ap_cat;
EditText ap_name;
EditText ap_desc;
EditText ap_rent;
ImageView ap_img;
Button ap_post;


String cat;



public static String image_url="";
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
```

public  String urii;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user__add_post);
    ap_cat=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ap_cat);
    ap_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ap_name);
    ap_desc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ap_desc);
    ap_rent=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ap_rent);
    ap_img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ap_img);
    ap_post=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ap_post);

    ap_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);



        }
    });
    ap_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            new UploadFileAsync().execute("");




        }
    });


    ap_cat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(i==0)cat="Electronics";
            else if(i==1)cat="Cameras";
            else if(i==2)cat="Cars";
            else if(i==3)cat="Bikes";
            else if(i==4)cat="Books";
            else if(i==5)cat="Mobiles";


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
        {

        }
    });




}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {

        Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        urii=picturePath;
        String[]a=picturePath.split("/");

        int ll=a.length-1;
       image_url= "http://conjunctive-appropr.000webhostapp.com/uploads"+a[ll];
        cursor.close();


        ap_img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));





    }


}
public void requestJsonObject()
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

   String url ="http://conjunctive-appropr.000webhostapp.com/uploads.php"+"&p1="+cat+"&p2="+ap_name.getText()+"&p3="+ap_desc.getText()+"&p4="+image_url+"&p5="+ap_rent.getText();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {





         /*   String temp="";
            int l=response.length();
            for(int i=0;i<response.length()-2;i++)
            {
                temp+=response.charAt(i);


            }*/

            id=0;
            if(id>0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Add post Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(User_AddPost.this,Agent_Menu.class));
            }
            else
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            requestJsonObject();
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}



class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String sourceFileUri = urii;

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                try {
                    String upLoadServerUri = "http://conjunctive-appropr.000webhostapp.com/uploads";

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                            "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math
                                .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                            + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn
                            .getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        // m
                        requestJsonObject();
                        // essageText.setText(msg);

                        int x=5;
                        //Toast.makeText(, "File Upload Complete.",
                        //    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    int x;

                }
                // dialog.dismiss();

            } // End else block


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // dialog.dismiss();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
    {

    }
}
```

}

i am expecting add successfully uploaded

Comment: please share your error log

Comment: E/libdataflow_monitor: open error=Operation not permitted

Comment: 15:00:53.258 5086-5530/com.example.usman.myapplication E/libdataflow_monitor: open error=Operation not permitted

Comment: and please edit the code. I don't understand it is very complicated and haven't seen all of codes.